# How to get a button to go to next page if page is valid- ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying that when the button "Create" is clicked and the page is valid it goes to next page. Code is listed below:

**Controller**

```
   public ActionResult Create()
        {

            return View(new Charity());
        }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ID,DisplayName,Date,Amount,TaxBonus,Comment")] Charity charity)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Donations.Add(charity);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("AdditionalInfo");
        }
        return View(charity);
    }
```

**Form (_Form)**

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <a href="~/Views/Charities/_Database2.cshtml">~/Views/Charities/_Database2.cshtml</a>

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Charity</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DisplayName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DisplayName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DisplayName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Date, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Date, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Date, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Amount, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Amount, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Amount, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TaxBonus, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TaxBonus, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TaxBonus, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Comment, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Comment, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Comment, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

**Create View**

```
@model CharitySite.Models.Charity

 @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Create";

 }

    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Donate-Style.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

      <div>  @Html.Partial("_Form", Model);</div> 

      <div> @Html.Action("_Database2");</div> @*Displays Table Table from Databa**@

        <div class="donatebtn">
            @Html.ActionLink("Donate", "Additionalinfo")
        </div>

        @section Scripts {
            @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
        }
```

I am trying to get it to the conroller name "AdditionalInfo" after validation is complete and user clicks the create button, right now it validates the form but it doesnt go to the next page when clicking the create button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to get it to the conroller name "AdditionalInfo"

Then you need to use a different overload.  This:

```
return RedirectToAction("AdditionalInfo");
```

will redirect the user to the `AdditionalInfo` *action* on the *current* controller.  To go to a different controller, you have to specify both the controller and the action:

```
return RedirectToAction("SomeAction", "AdditionalInfo");
```

Comment: To elaborate more on what David just wrote (which is correct), this will NOT maintain the state of the information that was just posted. You will have to pass that information to your next action, and back through the page, etc...or you can store it in a cache server or database. If you are certain your application will never be load balanced across more than one server, you can also store it in memory in cache or session.

Comment: @ohiodoug Thaks for the answer and yes the information is stored in a database.

Comment: Or save a trip from the database and pass it using the RouteCollection overload?

Comment: @DPac It's an option but if he's building something like an account-creation wizard then this could pose as a problem as he'd have to render this data back to his form (probably as hidden fields) and then re-validate all of it on the next post. Depending on the circumstance, you're doing an awful lot of re-work and opening the door a crack to vulnerabilities. Unless they have or are anticipating performance issues, I'd stick with the database.

Answer (score 0):

if addiitonalInfo is a controller you must call it this way :

```
this.RedirectToAction("YourActionName","addiitonalInfo")
```

you called wrong override of RedirectToAction method and it's looking for "addiitonalInfo" actionName in current ccontroller